# Gradle tasks from build.gradle are not getting listed

Tags: gradle

The gradle task that I have added to my build.gradle is not getting listed.

This is how my build.gradle looks

```
task helloWorld {
  doLast {
   println 'Hello world from gradle.'    
  }
}
```

However when I run `gradle tasks` the task `helloWorld` is not listed. Please help.

The gradle version is the following.

```
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-03-03 19:45:41 UTC
Revision:     9eb76efdd3d034dc506c719dac2955efb5ff9a93

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_31 (Oracle Corporation 25.31-b07)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64
```

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#tutorial_gradle_command_line: *By default, this report shows only those tasks which have been assigned to a task group, so-called visible tasks. You can do this by setting the group property for the task. You can also set the description property, to provide a description to be included in the report.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we need to use --all switch. The following works.

```
$ gradle tasks --all
```